# Tikz: error plotting function with parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Could you spot the error?
I'm trying to plot a function with two parameters, the initial condition of a differential equation.
The same pattern works for simple functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{arrow/.style={-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm, sep=0.5pt]}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,
declare function={ fctP(\x,\a,\b) = (sqrt(\b)+(\x-\a)/2)**2;
                   fctN(\x,\a,\b) = - (sqrt(-\b)+(\a-\x)/2)**2; }]
  \draw [arrow] (-2.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node [below]  {$x$};
  \draw [arrow] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2) node [right] {$y$};

  \draw[samples=200,domain=1:3,smooth,variable=\x,thick]  plot ({\x},{fctP(\x,3,1)}) node[above right] {$?$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using `**` instead of `^` for  `pgfmath` exponentiation. I also adjusted the axes ranges and removed a few things that you don't use. I'm leaving the definition of `fctN()` on purpose for the example of how to define several `pgfmath` functions at once, but it isn't used in the code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm, sep=0.5pt]}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,
                    declare function={
                      fctP(\x,\a,\b) = (sqrt(\b)+(\x-\a)/2)^2;
                      fctN(\x,\a,\b) = - (sqrt(-\b)+(\a-\x)/2)^2; }]
  \def\myxMax{3.0}
  \draw [arrow] (-0.2,0) -- (\myxMax,0) node [below]  {$x$};
  \draw [arrow] (0,-0.2) -- (0,1.2) node [right] {$y$};

  \draw[samples=200, domain=1:\myxMax, smooth, variable=\x, thick]
    plot ({\x}, {fctP(\x,3,1)}) node[above right] {$?$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the `\usetkzobj{all}` I removed is also causing a problem on my computer (`Command \tkzMarkRightAngle already defined).` I don't know if it is a `tkz-euclide` bug or a problem with my installation. Anyway, since `tkz-euclide` isn't used in your example, removing this line (as well as `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`) solves the problem. I sent a mail to the author of `tkz-euclide` with this minimal code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all} you can remove this line with the new version

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

No need to bother him more. :)

## Completed plot from the OP (@PeptideChain)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  bullet/.style={circle, fill, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
  arrow/.style={-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm, sep=0.5pt]}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
                    declare function={
                      fctP(\x,\a,\b) = (sqrt(\b)+(\x-\a)/2)^2;
                      fctN(\x,\a,\b) = - (sqrt(-\b)+(\a-\x)/2)^2; }]
  \draw [arrow] (-2.4,0) -- (3.4,0) node [below] {$x$};
  \draw [arrow] (0,-1.4) -- (0,1.4) node [right] {$y$};

  \draw[samples=200, domain=1:3.2, smooth, variable=\x, thick]
    plot ({\x}, {fctP(\x,3,1)}) node[above right] {$y(x)$};
  \draw[samples=200, domain=0:1, smooth, variable=\x, thick]
    plot ({\x},{0});
  \draw[samples=200, domain=-2.2:0, smooth, variable=\x, thick]
    plot ({\x}, {fctN(\x,-2,-1)});

  \draw (1,0)  -- node [below] {$1$}  (1,-0.03);
  \draw (2,0)  -- node [below] {$2$}  (2,-0.03);
  \draw (3,0)  -- node [below] {$3$}  (3,-0.03);
  \draw (-1,0) -- node [above] {$-1$} (-1,-0.03);
  \draw (-2,0) -- node [above] {$-2$} (-2,-0.03);
  \draw (0,1)  -- node [left]  {$1$}  (-0.03,1);
  \draw (0,-1) -- node [right] {$-1$} (-0.03,-1);

  \node[bullet, minimum size=3pt] at (3,1) {};
  \node[bullet, minimum size=3pt] at (-2,-1) {};
  \draw [dotted] (0,1)  -- (3,1);
  \draw [dotted] (3,0)  -- (3,1);
  \draw [dotted] (-2,0) -- (-2,-1);
  \draw [dotted] (0,-1) -- (-2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: completed plot]

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that the error message of Tikz says just nothing.

Comment: Yes, debugging is not always easy, especially with LaTeX. That is why MWEs are so useful. :)

Comment: May I edit your post and replace your code with my complete code adjusted with your correction?

Comment: How so? What is missing in my code?

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your code, my model was not finished, so it look prettier (second part of the curve, tiks, label)

Comment: you can always reverse the change

Comment: Okay, go for it.

Comment: @frougon With the new version of tkz-euclide you need to remove `\usetkzobj{all}`